# Using Microsoft SQL Server, incrementing a column based on table data

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

How do I make 'Item count' increment for every item going in `ReportID`?

As you can see, a `reportId` can have several `ShipNumbers` and a `ShipNumber` can have several `shipitems`.

`ShipNumber` and `ShipItem` are foreign keys to a `ShipLineTable`. Item Count and `ReportId` are the primary keys of this table `ReportLineTable`.

I need to know how to insert into this table, `ReportLineTable`, the item count column and have it increment for every item that is under a report ID. For example, report ID 1 has 3 items from two shipnumbers (1111, 2222), I need my Item Count column to increment for each item in the report ID. I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

FYI ShipItem keeps count of the items in a ShipNumber and this table has already been created. ReportLineTable grabs info from this table and I need to increment item count.

```
| Item count | Report ID | ShipNumber | ShipItem 
    1            1           1111         1
    2            1           1111         2
    3            1           2222         1
    1            2           3333         1 
    2            2           3333         2
    3            2           3333         3 
    4            2           4444         1
    5            2           4444         2          
    1            3           5555         1
    2            3           6666         2 
    1            4           7777         1
    2            4           8888         1
    3            4           8888         2 
    4            4           9999         1 
    5            4           9999         2
```

**Edit**: tried this but I get primary key violation

```
Dim NextItemCount as integer
dim lastitemcount as integer

Dim MaxItemCount As String = "SELECT MAX(ItemCount) FROM ReportLineTable WHERE ReportID= @ReportID"
        Dim MaxItemCountCommand As New SqlCommand(MaxItemCount, con)
        MaxItemCountCommand .Parameters.Add("@ReportID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = NextItemCount
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
        Try
            LastItemCount = CInt(MaxItemCountCommand.ExecuteScalar)
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            LastItemCount = 0
        End Try
        con.Close()
        NextItemCount = LastItemCount + 1
```

I use `NextItemCount` in my insert

```
   Insert in ReportLineTable (enter every column including ItemCount, values (@Itemcount)",con)
   parameters.add(@ItemCount.SqlDbInt).value = NextItemCount
```

Comment: do I have to loop through every shipitem in a report id and increment item count for each shipitem?

Comment: How is this different than your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44119203/1070452).  Note that it is very bad to delete a question someone took the time to answer.

Comment: I tried what someone answered and I can't get it to work so I wanted to try to ask again but with more detail since my last question stopped getting attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gave me the results I needed:

```
"INSERT INTO ReportLineTable 
(ItemCount) 
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY @ReportID ORDER BY ShipNumber) AS ItemCount 
FROM ShipLineTable"
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by reportId order by itemcount) as reportlinetable
from t;
```

Comment: it was close enough to what I needed that I was able to use it and figure out the rest, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can execute this SQL code without problems. I don't know if this is exactly what you want but I hope this helps. The code is in SQL but you can create a stored procedure o trigger to automatize the process.

I've used this table with the columns you've published.

```
create table ReportLineTable 
(
    itemCount int,
    reportCount int,
    shipNumber int,
    shipItem int
    primary key (itemCount, reportCount)
)

begin 
    Declare @itemNumber int;
    Declare @reportCount int = 100;

    select 
        @itemNumber = MAX(itemCount) + 1 
    from 
        ReportLineTable
    where 
        reportCount = @reportCount;

    if @itemNumber is NULL 
        set @itemNumber = 1;

    insert into ReportLineTable 
    values(@itemNumber, @reportCount, 10000, 1);
end;
-- 10000 and 1 we'll be values from the other table ! Here as example.
```

best luck

Miquel